# Is it possible to deploy Microsoft PDW on Azure?

Tags: sql-server-pdw

I've read about it and want to play around with it for a bit.

I think it requires a minimum of 4-5 machines to run, which is feasible with Azure IaaS, but how do I actually deploy it there?

Comment: No, [APS (new name for PDW)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/analytics-platform-system/) is not available in Azure, though I'm sure it will make its way there eventually.

Comment: @AaronBertrand oh.. so there is no way to actually install APS? You need to purchase an appliance only?

Comment: Currently yes I believe that is the only way - your regional [Microsoft Technology Center (MTC)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mtc/default.aspx) might be able to help you catch a glimpse, as multiple centers have on-site installations or remote access. Another way would be to land a consulting or remote DBA gig with an actual customer with their own appliance.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you have seen the [Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-data-warehouse/) announcements by now. It is Microsoft's data warehouse as a service offering. The syntax is very similar to PDW and it is also massively parallel like PDW.